# Selecting fields from UserForm and pulling data from another sheet using those selected fields

Tags: excel, vba, userform

multi part question. I have a UserForm, where the user selects 1 or more of 52 fields and i need those fields pasted as headers on another file. Originally i accomplished this with the code below, but i fee like there is a better way.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim index As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Set ls = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
Set ASR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Combined ASR")
Set cell = ls.Range("C1")
For index = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
cell.Value = UserForm1.ListBox1.List(index)
Set cell = cell.Offset(1)
End If
Next



Unload UserForm1
Worksheets("List").Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Copy
Worksheets("Combined ASR").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Secondly, i need to perform a vlookup to another dataset based on the fields they select. Currently i cannot think of a way to dynamically have it identify which field was selected and perform the vlookup from there. My only thought is to do something like this. But again i feel like there is a better way since field BA could be any of the available 52 fields. ( i only included 7 of the 52 fields below as an example).

```
Sub fields()

Set ASR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Combined ASR")

Dim F1 As String
Dim F2 As String
Dim F3 As String
Dim F4 As String
Dim F5 As String
Dim F6 As String
Dim F7 As String

F1 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,2,0)"
F2 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,3,0)"
F3 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,4,0)"
F4 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,5,0)"
F5 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,6,0)"
F6 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,7,0)"
F7 = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA,8,0)"

If ASR.Range("BA1") = "EMP_Status_CD" Then
ASR.Range("BA2") = F1
ElseIf ASR.Range("BA1") = "EMP_DEPARTMENT_ID" Then
ASR.Range("BA2") = F2
ElseIf ASR.Range("BA1") = "EMP_DEPARTMENT_NAME" Then
ASR.Range("BA2") = F3
ElseIf ASR.Range("BA1") = "LEVEL5_ID" Then
ASR.Range("BA2") = F4
ElseIf ASR.Range("BA1") = "LEVEL5_NAME" Then
ASR.Range("BA2") = F5
ElseIf ASR.Range("BA1") = "LEVEL6_ID" Then
ASR.Range("BA2") = F6
Else
ASR.Range("BA1") = "LEVEL6_NAME"
ASR.Range("BA2") = F7
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, one *question* per question on SO. And "I feel" is not really a question.

Comment: I feel like your comment was unnecessary.  I think you can easily understand what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: It's not a matter if or if not your questions  are understandable or not. It's a matter on how SO works: One question, one answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your fields selection could easily be handled by a bit of string assembly:

```
Sub fields()

Dim ASR as Worksheet
Dim Titles as Variant
Dim Target as String
Dim Res as Integer
Dim Col as Integer
Dim ThisTitle as string

Titles = Array("EMP_Status_CD", "EMP_DEPARTMENT_ID", "LEVEL5_ID", "LEVEL5_NAME", "LEVEL6_ID", "LEVEL6_NAME")

Set ASR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Combined ASR")
Target = ASR.Range("BA1").Text

Res = -1
Col = 2 ' initially
For Each ThisTitle in Titles
    If Target = ThisTitle Then
        Res = Col
        Exit For
    End If
    Col = Col + 1
Next ThisTitle

If Res <> -1 Then
    ASR.Range("BA2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('Combined ASR'!A2,HR_Data!A:BA," & Str(Res) & ",0)"
End If

End Sub
```

WARNING: untested

Additionally if you can initialize `Titles` from somewhere on the spreadsheet you would potentially have a neat way to pick the correct column in a fairly general-purpose way.